# Dynamic CPUs per Task in Spark

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say my job performs several spark actions, where the first few are not using multiple cores for a single task so I would like each instance to perform (`executor.cores`) tasks in parallel (`spark.task.cpus=1`).

Then suppose I have another action which can be parallelized - I'm desiring a feature where I could increase `spark.task.cpus` (say to use more cores on the executor), and perform fewer tasks simultaneously on each instance.

My workaround right now is to save data, start a new `sparkContext` with new settings, and reload the data.

The use case: my later actions may be unavoidable skewed and I may want to apply more than one core per task to avoid bottlenecking on such large tasks, but I don't want this to impact the earlier actions which can benefit from using 1 core per task.

From looking around my guess is that I can't do this currently, so I'm mainly wondering if there is a a significant limitation for not allowing this. Alternatively, suggestions for how I could trick spark into achieving something similar.

Note: Currently using 1.6.2 but willing to hear other options for Spark2+

Comment: Let's assume multiprocessing or an equivalent

Comment: Were you ever able to achieve anything to this effect?

Comment: @retrocookie were you able to find any solution having exactly same situation

Comment: Our hacky work around was to start a new spark context with different settings for spark.task.cpus reloading data was a smaller cost